# What are the return semantics of an async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, return, eslint

I'm trying to wrap my head around the [no-return-await](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await) rule.

Consider this snippet:

```js
const a = async () => {
    return 5;
};

const b1 = async () => {
    return a();
};

const b2 = async () => {
    return await a();
};

const wut = async () => {
    console.log(await b1());
    console.log(await b2());
};

wut();
```

Every async function returns a promise, so `a()` returns a promise. In this case I expect that `b1()` also wraps a promise, so the result would be a nested promise. Retrieving the value would require a double await, like in `b2`, but this does not seem required as both `console.log`'s return the value properly. What's going on? Are nested promises resolved recursively? I'm lost. Thanks for any pointers and explanation!

Comment: `the result would be a nested promise.` no - the resolution procedure would mean that the promise returned by b1 and b2 are the same (not the same promise, but the same resolved value)

Comment: "*Are nested promises resolved recursively?*" - yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

This is how promises behave in general and is not specific to the async/await syntax.

If a promise is resolved with another promise, then it effectively turns itself into that promise instead of resolving immediately.